# Probability of chosen topics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say a course has $20$ topics and $35$ questions divided so that $15$ topics have $2$ questions each and $5$ have $1$ If my tests are all $30$ questions long, what's the set up to calculate if all $20$ topics are represented (or $19$, $18$, etc.)? I need to know if it's likely that (e.g.) only $15$ topics are represented in a given test (which I think is a rare scenario).

I think this is an n choose r problem, with $35$ choose $30$ in the denominator, but I can't get the numerator to work out.

Comment: On second look it's a bit more difficult, cause even if I have a setup of 30 choose x and 5 choose y, that doesn't show if 18 topics are sampled in the test vs. 17 or 19.

Comment: To have all topics present you need to get $\binom{15}{5}$ because all 5 1q topics mist be present and this is a way to select 5 topics represented with 1 question

Comment: Doesn't $\binom{15}{5}$ simply show how many ways you can pick five from a set of 15? How does this equate to having all topics present?

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think you need inclusion-exclusion theorem. The denominator is $\binom{35}{30}$. Now for the numerator. All 1q topics must be present, so just subtract this number. For the 2q topics, think about 30 slots split into 2-slot bins. You need to put 5 red balls and 25 white balls such that no 2 red balls are in the same bin. There is a total of $\binom{30}{5}$ allocations. From this we subtract all allocations with at least 1 bin with 2 red balls:$\binom{15}{1}\binom{28}{3}$ and then add all allocations with two bins with red balls: $\binom{15}{2} \binom{26}{1}$.